# MySQL install error?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a lamp server running on my ubuntu installation. I have SSH and Apache working without any problems.

I installed MySQL with 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client

As usual with proir installations i've done it asked for a password. And looked like everything was fine. Except when i tried to test it out.
mysql -u root -p
Error Can't connect to local mysql server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

I went to the file location and there was no mysqld.sock file. I googled around for a while, and one response was to restart via /etc/init.d/mysqld restart.

**there's no mysqld file in my init.d folder either!!??** What's going on here? Any suggestions? How can i install and reinstall mysql? Is there some reason that the mysql service isn't installing?

Answer (score 0):

The file is called

```
/etc/init.d/mysql
```

not `mysqld`.

You can use also

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Check afterwards if MySQL is running: you can use e.g. `top` or `htop` or run `ps -aux|grep mysql`.

Comment: Yeah, messed up on the question. It's a fresh install of mysql.
`service mysql start`
works okay, but mysql doesn't start.

grep returns
`root      7008  5892  0 14:19 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
`

and mysql -u root -p returns
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: Please did you put any password for your MySQL user?